# JsonDocument - Read child object

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object that I'm trying to read properties from.  Here is a sample:

```
{"id":"335057af-a156-41c6-a0de-0cdc05856b3d",
"title":"Test 100488-100489 not included",
"code":"QWNCY47Y999",
"start":"2022-08-10T22:00:00.000Z",
"end":"2022-08-11T02:00:00.000Z",
"closeAfter":"2022-08-08T23:59:00.000Z",
"archiveAfter":"2022-11-08T22:00:00.000Z",
"timezone":"America/New_York",
"defaultLocale":"enUS",
"currency":"USD",
"registrationSecurityLevel":"Public",
"status":"Pending",
"eventStatus":"Upcoming",
"planningStatus":"In-Planning",
"testMode":true,
"planners":[{"firstName":"C","lastName":"G","email":"Noreply@events.qwerty.comx"}],
"created":"2021-06-11T09:55:57.667Z",
"lastModified":"2021-07-08T17:21:48.039Z",
"customFields":[
    {"id":"f2cf4864-171f-44fa-919a-248d37e42563",
    "name":"Level of Service",
    "value":["Full Support"],
    "type":"SingleSelect",
    "order":25},
    {"id":"c1539edf-a3e1-4f40-9747-e93f4fedfa5d",
    "name":"Internal/External",
    "value":["Internal","External"],
    "type":"MultiSelect",
    "order":42},
    {"id":"1b525d2a-b3f8-4141-91ae-45de5ee3a2fe",
    "name":"Request ID",
    "value":["MRF000558"],
    "type":"AutoIncrement",
    "order":53}],
"category":{"name":"Conference"},
"_links":{"invitation":{"href":"http://sandbox-www.qwerty.com/d/8nqg6n/1Q"},
"agenda":{"href":"http://sandbox-www.qwerty.com/d/8nqg6n/6X"},
"summary":{"href":"http://sandbox-www.qwerty.com/d/8nqg6n"},
"registration":{"href":"http://sandbox-www.qwerty.com/d/8nqg6n/4W"}},
"virtual":false,
"format":"In-person"}
```

I can programmatically read string properties, but if one of the properties is another object, I can't read it.

```
try 
{
        var x1 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("code");      // it works
        var x2 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("currency");   // it works
        var x3 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("start");     // it works

        var x99 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("summary");      // exception, key not found
        var x999 = x99.GetProperty("href");
}
catch(System.Exception ex)
{
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Ultimately, my goal is to read the `summary` child object and get property `href`.

Comment: Something else must be wrong, because `GetProperty()` works on JSON objects. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zEqtm9

Comment: My guess is that `KeyNotFoundException` is not thrown in the line you think it is. Maybe there is another property name, not shown in the example, but that you mispelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a bug. "summary" goes after "_links"

this works for me

```
var contentObj = JObject.Parse(content);

var href = contentObj["_links"]["summary"]["href"];
```

output

```
http://sandbox-www.qwerty.com/d/8nqg6n
```

for you I guess it could be

```
var x9 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("_links");
var x99 = x9.GetProperty("summary");     
 var x999 = x99.GetProperty("href").ToString();
//or just
var x999 = content2.RootElement.GetProperty("_links").GetProperty("summary").GetProperty("href").ToString();
```

Comment: That's Newtonsoft JSON though. OP is using `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thanks  for notice. I am suggesting how it should be in text.json. Pls check my updated answer

Comment: Good catch with the parent property `_links`. Goes to show that pretty printers have their use ^^

Comment: @Serge - THANK YOU.  I should have been able to figure this out on my own, but in my defense, I was looking at it after midnight.  From what I was seeing, it looked like `GetProperty()` didn't work with child objects, but I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Unless this "but if one of the properties is another object, I can't read it." means that you don't have a well defined format for your JSON file, just create an object for your JSON file and deserialize it. Then you can access it directly via that objects property.

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid defining an object to deserialize to.  This object is coming from a third-party API, and might not be consistent format.

Comment: @Joe: I concur with not deserializing everything if performance is more of a concern than readability... but if the json is in an inconsistent format, your method has the same problem. You're simply hard coding the format in ugly code lines rather than in the class structure.

Comment: @DevinBurke - Yes, normally I'd agree.  In this case, adding or removing an unrelated property to the response should not affect getting the one property I need.  If that one property that I need is no longer available through the API, then the whole thing would have to be reworked.  I guess this is just the lesser of two evils.